# ASP.NET MVC Login using Jquery: validating if credentials are valid

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

This might be a wierd question, but I am just asking to check if that doable or I miss something.

I am using identity server and have this login action in my account Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // validate username/password against in-memory store
        var user = new SecurityCore.Models.User();

        var compasLoginReponse = UserLogin(model.UserName, model.Password);

        if (compasLoginReponse.IsSuccess)
        {
            //set the user logged in 
            user = compasLoginReponse.Entity;

            // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username             
            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(user.Subject, user.UserName);

            // make sure the returnUrl is still valid, and if yes - redirect back to authorize endpoint
            if (_interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
            }
            return Redirect("~/");
        }
    }         

    //this is bad practice , but just for the purpose if testing
    return Ok("false");
}
```

I am trying to use jquery post in order to prevent the page from refreshing or making a postback if the credentials are wrong (when the user is valid he is redirectecd to other url which includes the token)

This my form and this my ajax function:

The click event handler for the login button

```js
 $("#login_button").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/Account/Login",
         data: { 'username': $("#username").val(), 
             'password': $("#password").val() },
         datatype: "json",
         success: function (result) {
             if (result === "false") {
                 //then alert the user for wrong    credentials
             }
         }
    });

    //if if omit this line then the return url will be pouplated otherwise, it will be null
    return false;
});
```

```html
@model IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.Models.LoginViewModel

  
<form asp-route="Login">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ReturnUrl" />
    <div  id="form-group-username">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Username" id="username">
    </div>
    <div  id="form-group-password">
        <label for="pwd">Password</label>
        <input type="password" asp-for="Password" id="password">
    </div>
     
    <button type="button" id="login_button">Login</button>
</form>
```

My Problem: The return url returning from this function in Login Action is always null.

```
if (_interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
```

If I omit the last line "return false" from the jquery function, then it works but the Action gets executed two times, the first time the return url is null and the next time it obtains the url.

It seems that it doens't work except if the page is submitted.

How can I achieve what I am intending to do? Is there any workaround to prevent the page from making a postback if the credential are wrong.

Comment: This makes no sense. The whole point of ajax is to stay to the same page and it will never redirect (your `return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);` etc is pointless). But your ajax method never sens a value for `ReturnUrl` anyway so its always `null`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks for answering taking into consideration that i am making false assumptions to prove something. Regarding the `ReturnUrl` as I said it gets populated if i removed the `return false` from js fiunction. Is that because its called twice which means the page was submitted causing identiy server to populate the url

Comment: Yes - you would be making a normal submit and the ajax submit (and to send the value in the ajax call, you would need to include `'ReturnUrl': $("#ReturnUrl").val()`). But there is no reason to use ajax here and because you would have to return the view and update it to display the error messages, there is no performance benefit anyway. Just make a normal submit.

Comment: Adding the `ReturnUrl` and posting it, succeeds in populating the ReturnUrl . However it didn't redirect it to the new url, unless i remove the `return false` from js function.

Comment: Of course it wont. Read my previous comments. Ajax calls **NEVER** redirect (the whole point is to stay on the same page) and it has nothing to do with Identity Server. Do not use ajax for this. Delete you script and make a normal submit and if `ModelState` is invalid, return the view.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, I wanted to prove that to my colleague and You helped me to do that.